# VBA - Excel for comparing two columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have created one VBA Which will compare the two sheets of same excel file. If the data in Sheet A is not accurate it will change the color of that row into red, also i have applied filter if my color gets changed.

Now the problem is It is not working in appropriate manner. Like if my data is same then also it is applying filter.

See my code below

```
Sub Validate_Metadata()
Dim myRng As Range
Dim lastCell As Long
Dim flag As Boolean

    'Get the last row
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'Debug.Print "Last Row is " & lastRow

    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False



    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
        For Each d In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
            c.Interior.Color = vbRed
            flag = False
             If (InStr(1, d, c, 1) > 0) Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbWhite
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

    If (flag <> True) Then

      ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0 _
        , 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Validate_Metadata()
  Dim myRng As Range
  Dim lastCell As Long
  Dim flag As Boolean

  'Get the last row
  Dim lastRow As Integer
  Dim localFlag As Boolean
  lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

  'Debug.Print "Last Row is " & lastRow

  Dim c As Range
  Dim d As Range

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False


  flag = True
  For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
    localFlag = False
    For Each d In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
        c.Interior.Color = vbRed
         If (InStr(1, d, c, 1) > 0) Then
            c.Interior.Color = vbWhite
            localFlag = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    flag = flag And localFlag
  Next

  If (flag <> True) Then

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, 
    Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0 _
    , 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
  End If

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are first changing the interior color of the cell to **red** and then checking for condition. If it matches you are then again changing cell color to **white**. I guess this is not a good approach. Instead first check the condition and then change the color only when there is no match.

Something like this:

```
Sub Validate_Metadata()
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim lastCell As Long
    Dim flag As Boolean, found As Boolean 'new boolean variable declared
    'Get the last row
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet11").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
        found = False 'set flag here for cell
        For Each d In Worksheets("Sheet12").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
            If (InStr(1, d, c, 1) > 0) Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbWhite
                found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next d
        If Not found Then 'if cell do not match change the color
            c.Interior.Color = vbRed
            If Not flag Then flag = True 'change filter flag to true just once
        End If
    Next c
    If flag Then 'check for filter flag
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0 _
        , 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```